# In Python, how does one integrate a vector-valued, higher-order function?

Tags: python, vector, integration, higher-order-functions

Normally, when we deal with integrating higher-order functions mapping from the real numbers to the real numbers, there isn't much fuss. For example:

```
def foo(n):
    def bar(x):
        return n * x
    return bar

func = foo(5)
```

func is easy to integrate when n is a scalar, but how would I accomplish integration of each of the components of func in the case that n is a d-dimensional vector?

Comment: Attempt to do the integration by hand and analyze the process that you use to do so, write that process down on paper and see if it can be expressed as pseudocode then converted to code. [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) or [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/) will probably help but you will need to spend some time learning them.

Comment: ```foo``` does not look like it will work - are you going to ask specific questions about fixing ```foo```?

Comment: Are you saying that within the snippet above, the component-wise integration is intractable and that I'll need to avoid using higher-order functions?

Comment: Nope, you had a mistake that you have corrected.

Comment: Intractable seems a bit subjective - I guess it depends on how much time and effort you can afford.

Comment: I actually know the expression which the integral is equal to, but it involves taking the component-wise derivative of func. Essentially, I'm still looking to somehow be able to iterate through each function component determined by func, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Not enough information (for me) and the math eludes me.  Iteration implies a loop, You may need to break it down into separate problems, try to solve each then put them together.  There may be a better StackExchange site to post this - this is mainly for coding problems rather than algorithm questions, but there are people here that could tackle it if they see it.  It helps to show, minimal, input and output examples. Examples of the process/equation you are trying to solve ...

Comment: You want to *feed* ```foo``` a multidimensional array and then ```func``` will be a *container* of callables based on the vector input and then operate on that *container*?  You may need to think about the problem differently, at least if you use NumPy, to realize the effect of a higher order function using a different approach, I'm no wizard and can just see the edges of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate each component separately. The indefinite integral of

```
[x, x**2, 2*exp(x), ...]
```

is

```
[0.5 * x**2, 1.0/3.0 * x**3, 2*exp(x), ...]
```